# How to concatenate email addresses listed in Excel sheet?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I want to grab email addresses, from column A in a sheet named macros, then send an attachment to those addresses.

I can send to an address individually, but when combined and a semicolon and a space, it produces

> Run-Time error: '-2147467259 (80004005) Outlook does not recognize one or more names.'

I tested changing full email addresses in macro sheet to Outlook check names text, manually typing the ToString value, and putting in a wait timer. The only thing that worked is changing `.Send` to `.Save` and letting Outlook realize that the semicolon is not part of the address, but separating 2 addresses can take up to 2 minutes without me intervening. Then I can send from drafts.

```
Sub Email()

 

Dim objOutlook As Outlook.Application

Dim objOutlookMsg As Outlook.MailItem

Dim objOutlookRecip As Outlook.Recipient

Dim objOutlookAttach As Outlook.Attachment

Dim WeekendingDate As Date

Dim ToString As String

 

Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

 

Set objOutlookMsg = objOutlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)

ToString = ""

With objOutlookMsg

For i = 2 To Worksheets("Macro").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

ToString = ToString & "; " & Worksheets("Macro").Cells(i, 1).Value

Next

 

ToString = Right(ToString, Len(ToString) - 2)

MsgBox ToString

Set objOutlookRecip = .Recipients.Add(ToString)

objOutlookRecip.Type = olTo

.Subject = "Test Subject"

.Body = "Test Body" & Now()

'Add attachments to the message

'[some code]

 

.Attachments.Add "file path to add"

 

For Each objOutlookRecip In .Recipients

objOutlookRecip.Resolve

Next

 

If DisplayMsg Then

.Display

Else

.Send

End If

End With

Set objOutlook = Nothing

 

End Sub
```

Comment: Instead of building a semi-colon separated string, why not just `.Recipients.Add( <value of cell> )` inside the loop that reads the cells?

Answer (score 1):

**There are so many Extra Lines in Your Code:**

```
Sub Email()

Dim objOutlook As Outlook.Application
Dim objOutlookMsg As Outlook.MailItem
Dim objOutlookRecip As Outlook.Recipient
Dim objOutlookAttach As Outlook.Attachment
Dim WeekendingDate As Date
Dim ToString As String

Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set objOutlookMsg = objOutlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)

ToString = ""

For i = 2 To Worksheets("Macro").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row

    ToString = ToString & "; " & Worksheets("Macro").Cells(i, 1).Value

Next

ToString = Right(ToString, Len(ToString) - 2)
MsgBox ToString



With objOutlookMsg
.Recipients.Add (ToString)
.Subject = "Test Subject"
.Body = "Test Body" & Now()
.Display
.Attachments.Add "file path to add"  'Add Attachments

If DisplayMsg Then
    .Display
Else
    .Send
End If

End With

Set objOutlook = Nothing

End Sub
```

This should work now. I have removed Extra Lines of code that is not required.

Comment: This now opens up Outlook into the check names screen and says it does not recognize the email address. It is trying to find "person1@company.com; person2@company.com" as one email address instead of splitting them up.

Comment: I tested the Code, It recognizes all of them Differently.

Comment: When the Mail opens, let it wait for few seconds, it will recognize all of them. Otherwise you can send the Email.

Comment: Just got it to work, put in the for loop into the with and inside instead of concsntonating the string, in said add recipient each loop.

Comment: There are no extra lines in the sample code posted. Recipients should be resolved against the address book.

Answer (score 0):

This error means that one of the email address is not legal or got forbidden characters for email address...

Like

> :